# How to use a global AccountController with different Views for each Area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an AccountController in the default Controllers folder of my ASP.NET MVC 3 internet application.

How can i use this AccountController as the global AccountController, but give it different layouts, depeing on which Area i am in?

I have an [Authorize] annotation on a Controller in an Area called "SmallSurvey". If the client is not logged in, it redirects him to the default AccountController, that uses the standard layout, which is not what i want.

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing the same Model to all Views?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following and it worked:

1- Create area

2- Under the area's Views directory, create a Home directory.

3- Under the Home directory create a View with the same name as the View you are using in your Global Home controller's action.

4- Access the area URL.

For example for Area Admin use the URL: /Admin/Home/MyAction

It goes to your Global Home Controller but it runs the View in the Area.

Comment: I made a folder called Account in the Views folder of my Area. Then i made a LogOn view (Similar to the default one). [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Respondent, Moderator")] sends users the original LogOn  View in the default Views folder :(

Comment: Have you checked your Web.Config? Look for this: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>  You will need to change that to point to your Area

Comment: But isnt this a global setting? If i am not in this specific Area, i would like to show the default LogOn view

Answer (score 0):

You could create a layout selector action filter which will use the `ReturnUrl` parameter to determine whether the initial request was for a controller located inside an area or not and based on this information pick an alternative layout:

```
public class LayoutSelectorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var returnUrl = request["returnurl"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            return;
        }
        var url = new Uri(new Uri(request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), returnUrl);
        var fakeRequest = new HttpRequest(null, url.AbsoluteUri, url.Query);
        var fakeResponse = new HttpResponse(TextWriter.Null);
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(fakeRequest, fakeResponse);
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
        var area = routeData.DataTokens["area"] as string;
        if (string.Equals(area, "SmallSurvey", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            result.MasterName = "~/Views/Shared/_SmallSurveyLayout.cshtml";
        }
    }
}
```

and then decorate your `AccountController` with it:

```
[LayoutSelector]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: request["returnurl"] should be request["ReturnUrl"]

Comment: @Kenci, the request dictionary is case agnostic.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Your method works fine when returnurl is not null. However, if i click on a link in a view (which uses the new MasterName _SmallSurveyLayout.cshtml) and returnurl is null, it will use the old layout. What can i do about this? - returnurl gets defined in UrlRefferer.Query